# How to get the sources of a npm package locally when developing?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am very new to node and npm and I am wondering if it is possible to work on a application, but also work on a local git repository for some node modules.

Let's say I am starting a new project that uses `chalk` and I would like to develop both on my project and on chalk.

```
mkdir my-project && cd my-project
npm install 
npm install --save chalk/chalk
```

With the above command I will the source of `chalk` into `node_modules` but I cannot contribute to it.

Is there a way to directly get the Git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming '~/projects' is your projects folder, first clone chalk:

```
cd ~/projects
git clone https://github.com/chalk/chalk.git
```

Then create your project:

```
mkdir my-project && cd my-project
npm init
```

And set your project to use your local chalk. Look for package.json file inside my-project and include chalk in dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "chalk": "file:../chalk"
    ....
    ....
```

Then install chalk in your project:

```
cd ~/my-project
npm install chalk
```

Or simply 'npm install' to install all your dependencies. Every time you need to include in your project changes you made on chalk type again 'npm install chalk'. It copies ~/chalk on ~/my-project/node_modules and uses it.

You can continue working on your project and on chalk.

Comment: Nice answer. I also learned that npm cannot do the trick by itself, so I should manually add a git submodule to get all the dependencies.